# How to style radio input button (ReactJS)?

Tags: css, reactjs

Would like to change the color of radio button:

[image]

However, it seems not working, still getting the default color:

[image]

Comment: Make sure `style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}`

Comment: Rather than inline styling here. I would suggest creating a classes because you would also need to style pseudo classes and pseudo elements for a radio button to have a custom styling. You can target input[type="radio"], and it's pseudo-element input[type="radio"]::before and it's checked stage input[type="radio"]:checked::before individually and with ease. It'll be difficult to tackle all these stylings with inline style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the radio button color directly, You need to build your own and customize it as you want.

or you can use `filter` with `hue-rotate()` but it's not supported on *Internet Explorer* have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate) for more info

**Edit**
There is a better way to do this as @Servesh Chaturvedi mentioned using `accent-color: red;`

```css
#one{
  filter: hue-rotate(150deg);
}

#two{
  accent-color:red;
}
```

```html
 <input type="radio" id="one" name="radio" value="first">
<label for="html">First</label><br>

 <input type="radio" id="two" name="radio" value="second">
<label for="html">Second</label><br>
```

Comment: I believe accent-color property also has good support now. just put `accent-color: red;` in the input

Comment: The `for` attribute needs to be set to the ID of the input it's tied to ("one" for the first label, "two" for the second one). This allows selecting the radio button by clicking it label, which you cannot do if you just set all `for` attributes to "html".